# Section header in a list

Tags: list, column

I have received a request for inserting a logical section header in a SharePoint List. The list contains some 15 fields and the customer would like to display 10 if the fields in one section and the remaining 5 fields in another by using some sort of section header for a total of 16 fields. In my opinion it sounds like any other field except that the input part of the field has been removed. Any ideas how I can tweak SharePoint into doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the "EDIT" screen for a list item (instead) ?

Meaning to have 10 fields - then a line break + some text - then the rest of the fields ?

You could have a custom EDIT page - just need to do a list def, and create a new ASCX/ASPX page for the edit screen.

(Or am I missing something - sorry if I misunderstood !)